# Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be three sets. Prove that if $A \setminus B \subseteq C$, then $A \setminus C \subseteq B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be three sets. Prove that if $A \setminus B \subseteq C$, then $A \setminus C \subseteq B$.

I was thinking of proving this with double inclusion but not too sure how I would approach it

Comment: Assume $x$ is in $A\setminus C$. Do you see why it has to be an element of $B$?

Comment: Maybe draw a Venn diagram of the three sets, and use that as a guide for your proof.

Comment: Suppose that each element of $A \setminus B$ is also an element of $C$. With this, prove that each element of $A \setminus C$ is also an element of $B$. Can you do this?

Comment: Double inclusion would be useful if you were trying to prove equality, since $S\subseteq T$ and $T\subseteq S$ implies $S=T$ among sets.

Comment: Note that both statements are equivalent to $A \subseteq (B \cup C)$.

Comment: Nice photograph of Albert Camus...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $(A \setminus B) \subset C$, and let $x \in A \setminus C$.

If you had $x \notin B$, then you would have $x \in A \setminus B$, so $x \in C$ by hypothesis. This is a contradiction. So $x \in B$.

So $(A \setminus C) \subset B$.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof:** Let $A, B$ and $C$ be any sets. Suppose that $A \setminus B \subseteq C.$ Let $x \in A \setminus C.$ By definition, we have that $x \in A,$ and $x \notin C.$ We will consider two cases, namely if $x \in B$ and if $x \notin B.$

Case $1:$ $x \in B.$ Hence we conclude that $A \setminus C \subseteq B.$

Case $2:$ $x \notin B.$ Hence $x \in A \setminus B.$ Then we have that $x \in C.$ Which is a contradiction. So this case cannot happen.

Therefore, we have that $A \setminus C \subseteq B.$ $\square$